# Extracting SST time series at multiple lat, lon locations using CDO

Tags: cdo-climate

Background: I am working with satellite observations of SST (time, lat, lon) from the CoRTAD SST dataset (netCDF file). I have a set of (lon,lat) coordinates following the coastal contour of Portugal (called below **midshelf locations**).  I want to extract the SST time series at each of these midshelf locations, average them and subtract the SST at the same latitudes but a fixed longitude to give a coastal SST index.

The midshelf lon,lats were determined first from a nautical chart, which were then linearly interpolated to the lon,lats in the CoRTAD grid.

How can this be done using CDO?
The lon,lats from the nautical map are given below.

---

midshelf lon,lats from the nautical map:

### -8.000  43.860
-9.000  43.420
-9.350  43.220
-9.388  42.893
-9.000  42.067
-8.935  41.308
-9.000  40.692
-9.278  40.000
-9.324  39.550
-9.518  39.387
-9.777  38.883
-9.285  38.378
-8.909  38.293
-8.951  38.000
-8.965  37.953
-8.917  37.833
-8.913  37.667
-8.915  37.500
-8.975  37.333
-9.017  37.167
-9.045  37.000

Comment: Hi Greg. As I mentioned on the YouTube channel comments it seems what you want to do is mask all the sea points that are next to coast and then average just those points to give you an index, is that correct? I can show you how to do this but just wanted to make sure this is what you require

Comment: So I think "masking" is probably one way to think about doing it.

Comment: "There is a bit more to it." Please state your problem clearly in the question. People are to help, but it's better to not leave them guessing about what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok last question. The lat lon points that are in a file, how are they located/calculated? Are they a fixed distance from the coast? Because it may be easier to derive them from scratch, unless they are in the form of a netcdf mask? Or are they are list in a text file?

Comment: Adrian, I rewrote my question and added information about how the (midshelf) locations were determined. The nautical map midshelf locations are interpolated to the SST grid and stored in a file that is read into a matlab script to extract the time series.

Comment: Robert Wilson: Sorry -- This is my first time submitting a question and took getting used to how to edit my question and respond to comments.  I have tried to tidy things up.  I think my question is pretty straightforward. But sounds like the solution (using cdo) is not straightforward.

Comment: @GregKing What is your actual question? Do you simply want to interpolate SST to a set of lat/lon? That is a fairly easy procedure

Comment: @RobertWilson  I think he wants to calculate the SST at that given set of lat lon points and then subtract the SST at the same lats, but lon=9E  to create an index... I was thinking one could loop over the lat-lon pairs and extract those points, get the average with ensmean and then do the same for lon=9E, but I don't know how to loop pairwise... If those points are selected using a depth requirement, I think it would be easier to do it using masking and a topography dataset (also ETOPO built into CDO) but I don't understand the criteria used to define those points yet.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins That part of the question has been removed, hence my confusion. From your description it sounds more like something you'd want to do in Python/Matlab/R.

Comment: yes you are right, the question is written differently now... and it does seem more of a task suitabler for python, I would agree

Comment: @RobertWilson had to give it a go in bash/cdo , was too tempting not to try ;-)

Comment: @AdrianTompkins Nice. You could also have done it by creating an unstructured grid with the lat/lons, though that can be a bit tedious if you don't have a script to do it

Comment: @AdrianTompkins ... My apologies for removing some of the question.  I got the idea that it made some confusion so I tried to give it better focus.  I guess that was not necessary to do.  Anyway, many thanks for the work you put in and solution you give.  I will get right to work on it and give you feedback.

Comment: @GregKing really no problem. Best just to ask what you want to know to avoid confusion. Hope the script works for you. Robert's approach is probably more efficient but I need to learn more on unstructured grids. But i think my script should work even if it is slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my attempt to answer the question as it was stated in the comments (i.e. you wanted an index which was the midshelf locations averaged and then subtracting the same latitude SST sampled at Longitude=9E). I assume the locations are stored pair-wise in a text file called "locations.txt" as in your question above.  The loop part of the answer is from one of [this question's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124211/read-text-file-two-words-at-a-time-in-a-loop-in-bash).

```
# first loop over the pairs of indices in the text files.
while read -r -a fields; do
    for ((i=0; i < ${#fields[@]}; i += 2)); do
        # precise lon/lat for sampled mid-shelf
        cdo remapnn,"lon=${fields[i]}/lat=${fields[i+1]}" in.nc pt_${i}.nc
        # same lat but lon=9E (change as wanted)
        cdo remapnn,"lon=9/lat=${fields[i+1]}" in.nc 9E_${i}.nc
    done
done < example.txt

# now take the ensemble average over the points.
cdo ensmean pt_*.nc mid_shelf_sst.nc  
cdo ensmean 9E_*.nc mid_shelf_9E.nc

# and calculate the index
cdo sub mid_shelf_sst.nc mid_shelf_9E.nc SST_index.nc
```