# read text file two words at a time in a loop in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xargs

I have a text file with a space separated list of numbers (lat/lon) that looks like this :

```
-8.000 43.860 -9.000 43.420 -9.350 43.220 -9.388 42.893 -9.000 42.067 -8.935 41.308 -9.000 40.692 -9.278 40.000 -9.324 39.550 -9.518 39.387 -9.777 38.883 -9.285 38.378 -8.909 38.293 -8.951 38.000 -8.965 37.953 -8.917 37.833 -8.913 37.667 -8.915 37.500 -8.975 37.333 -9.017 37.167 -9.045 37.000
```

I know how to loop through the numbers one by one in bash like this

```
awk '{ for ( i = 1; i < NF; ++i ) print $(i); }' example.txt |
while IFS= read -r lon lat
do 
    echo processing: "$lon $lat" 
done
```

giving:

```
processing: -8.000 
processing: 43.860 
processing: -9.000 
processing: 43.420 
processing: -9.350 
processing: 43.220
```

etc, but how can I loop through the file pair-wise?

i.e. something like (but this obviously doesn't work):

```
while IFS= read -r lon lat
do 
    echo processing: "$lon $lat " 
done
```

to give me lon=-8, lat=43.86 on the first loop etc...?

Comment: `awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)print $i, $(i+1)}' file | ...`

Comment: I'm so stupid, of course the awk command, doh, I was half asleep, thank you!

Comment: Just don't erase the IFS, don't use `IFS=`. It look like you put `IFS=` just because you'v seen it many times, but did not catch what it really does, when using it and when not, or when using other values.

Comment: Also shell will not be able to process floats

Comment: @Lea, you caught me, I'm a bit of a cut-paste hack when it comes to bash I'm afraid... :-(

Comment: No shame for copy-pasting. Avoid redoing the same work over and over again, and not reinventing the wheel are some of the sanest motivations to code. Now copy-pasting has its own pitfalls if you skip the extra step to understand how the code you copy actually works.

Comment: @LéaGris yes you are completely right... I need to find the time to brush up my bash skills in fact...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read all the fields in a line into an array (with `read -a`), and then loop over that:

```bash
while read -r -a fields; do
    for ((i=0; i < ${#fields[@]}; i += 2)); do
        echo "${fields[i]}" "${fields[i+1]}"
    done
done < example.txt
```

```
-8.000 43.860
-9.000 43.420
-9.350 43.220
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Using xargs

```
$ echo "key1 value1 key2 value2" | xargs -n2 
key1 value1
key2 value2

$ echo "a b c e f g" | xargs -n3 
a b c
e f g
```

---

```
while IFS= read -r lon lat; do 
    echo processing: "$lon $lat" ; 
done < <(xargs -n2 <example.txt)

processing: -8.000 43.860 
processing: -9.000 43.420 
processing: -9.350 43.220 
processing: -9.388 42.893 
...
```

Without while loop

```
$ xargs -n 2 sh -c 'echo processing: lon $1 lat $2' argv0 <example.txt
processing: lon -8.000 lat 43.860
processing: lon -9.000 lat 43.420
processing: lon -9.350 lat 43.220
processing: lon -9.388 lat 42.893
processing: lon -9.000 lat 42.067
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{ 
    for ( i = 1; i < NF; i+=2 ) 
        print $i, $(i+1) 
}' file | 
while read -r lon lat
do
    echo processing: "$lon $lat"
done
```

Output:

```
processing: -8.000 43.860 
processing: -9.000 43.420 
processing: -9.350 43.220 
...
```

Comment: You'll need to remove `IFS=` -- $lon contains "-8.000 42.860" and $lat is empty. Verify with `echo "$lon:$lat"`

Comment: in fact, I was using this solution with a single variable parsed with a "/" as I was passing the argument directly to CDO - thanks for the comment though

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, just copy&pasted the sample and fixed the awk.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E  '/([0-9.-]+ [0-9.-]+) ?/s//processing: \1\n/g' example.txt
processing: -8.000 43.860
processing: -9.000 43.420
processing: -9.350 43.220
processing: -9.388 42.893
processing: -9.000 42.067
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs`:

```bash
xargs -n 2 env LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'Processing: %.3f %.3f\n' < example.txt
```

Using only `awk`,
`awkscript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f
{
  i = 1;
  while(i < NF) {
    lon = $i;
    i++;
    lat = $i;
    i++;
    printf("Processing: %.3f %.3f\n", lon, lat);
  }
}
```

```bash
chmod +x awkscript
./awkscript example.txt
```

Or one-line: `awk '{i=1;while(i<NF){lon=$i;i++;lat=$i;i++;printf("Processing: %.3f %.3f\n",lon,lat);}}' < example.txt`